# Why doesn't the timezonedb extension have the latest data?

Tags: php, docker

I've created a Dockerfile, and I use the `wordpress:php7.4-apache`.

I've tried to install the timezonedb extension using 3 different methods separately.

Method 1.

```
RUN docker-php-source extract \
    && pecl bundle -d /usr/src/php/ext timezonedb \
    && docker-php-ext-configure timezonedb \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) timezonedb \
    && docker-php-source delete
```

Method 2.

```
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/src/pecl \
    && pecl bundle -d /usr/local/src/pecl timezonedb \
    && docker-php-ext-configure /usr/local/src/pecl/timezonedb \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) /usr/local/src/pecl/timezonedb \
    && rm -rf /usr/local/src/pecl
```

Method 3.

```
RUN apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config \
    && pecl install timezonedb \
    && bash -c "echo extension=timezonedb.so > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-timezonedb.ini"
```

The 3 methods work properly. After building the docker container, I confirm that the extension is installed and loaded properly by checking the PHP information:

CLI:
[image: PHP Info - CLI]

Web:
[image: PHP Info - Web]

The timezonedb uses the latest version which according to [the pecl site](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb) is version `2022.7`.

I've checked [the timezonedb github file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/php/pecl-datetime-timezonedb/master/timezonedb.h), and there should be 597 timezones.

But, upon checking the timezonedb array, I can see it only contains 420 timezones.
[image: TimezoneDB array content]

So, the question is, why is it so different? What did I miss here?

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does a timezonedb verion have to do with docker or php (tagging). I would expect hat the OS image or whatever has the timezone db is outdated - there is no connection here to PHP or Docker that looks relevant.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I did it the right way, that's all.

Comment: Nope,you did not. See, PHP is irreleant as is docker to a degree, but mostly I would point timezonedb as tag

Comment: Given that this is a docker / Programming thing, I think this is better off at stackoverflow than serverfault.

Comment: PHP 7.4 is end-of-lifed, so it's not that surprising instances with it are too. https://www.php.net/eol.php

Comment: @TomTom, the issue I posted is related to how the timezonedb extension is installed and I needed to know whether I installed it the right way, that's why I posted it here, if you can't help, don't bother to complain, my post isn't worth your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

everything all right!
just try to use `ALL_WITH_BC` timezone group.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php

```
echo 'ALL : ';
echo count(timezone_identifiers_list(DateTimeZone::ALL)); // -> result : 425
echo '<br/>';

echo 'ALL_WITH_BC : ';
echo count(timezone_identifiers_list(DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC)); // -> result : 593
echo '<br/>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the dev didn't give me detailed information on what he did. But, I think this was the workaround. I'll mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think fundamentally this boils down to the tag `php7.4-apache` in combination with probably just what was included in the underlying OS image at the time. (As the question in the image says it uses an "external" database, I assume this is the OS-provided one.)

If you have a quick look at [`wordpress` Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) page, they have no `php7.4-apache` in their list of *supported* tags anymore.
And searching for this one finds [this commit](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/commit/9805367fb85866f8a273a0c983f274e3be98638a) in the corresponding repository, noting how php 7.4 is EOL and they therefore removed the support for it.

Ie, it appears that everything is outdated in the image tagged this way as it is no longer maintained, not limited to the Olsen database.

I think the security side of this situation should probably be seen as more concerning than the outdated Olsen database.

I think it would probably be a good idea to pick a less specific tag (even `latest`, or `apache`, or `6` or `6-apache` or whatever might fit your requirements) unless you actually have very specific requirements.
And if you do have requirements that forces you into using some more specific tag, you will simply have to keep in mind that such a specific tag will probably have a shorter lifetime than a more general one, and stay in touch with what its status is.

Comment: I tried this before, the WP site was broken when I used the latest version, so I have to "lock" the image to that tag :(

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone stumbles with the same case, I hope this helps.

So, the dev finally reached out to me, saying he finally managed to get the correct timezones.

He said he had to use the PHP wrapper to get the timezones.

This confirms that the timezonedb installation is correct.

I'd like to thank you @ceejayoz and @håkan-lindqvist for your help, I really appreciate this, took quite some time for me to solve this case.